# Creating Annotation in MapKit with information from UITableview while using segue

Tags: php, ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit

I am currently working on developing an application that pulls data (Address and location information) from a php web service and displays the data as a string in a tableview cell. My tableview is embedded in a Navigation controller, when a cell is clicked a segue links to a map with several hard-coded pins on the map.

I am interested in creating a segue that links a tableview cell (Address)  to a specific pin/annotation in a map as a direct reference to the address.

Additionally, I am interested in creating a custom annotation that displays data (Name, Address, photo etc.) regarding its location.

Ideally I am trying to recreate a simpler version of SpotHero.

Thanks!

Heres Some of my code:

TableController:

class TableController: UITableViewController {

```
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var garagedata :Array<String> = Array < String >()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    get_data_from_url("http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team20/service.php")
}



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    //Wrap text in tableview
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines=0

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //Automatic sizing of tableviewcells
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Segue to the second view controller
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let mapController = segue.destination as! MapController

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the data to pass
    mapController.receivedData = "Hello"
}

func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

           return
        }


        self.extract_json(data!)


    }) 

    task.resume()

}


func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{


    let json: Any?

    do
    {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
    catch
    {
        return
    }

    guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
    {
        return
    }


    if let garages_list = json as? NSArray
    {

        let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count

        /*{
            print(TableData)
            if let garage_obj = garages_list[i] as? NSDictionary

            {
                if let garage_name = garage_obj["GName"] as? String
                {
                if let garage_address = garage_obj["Address"] as? String
                {
                    if let garage_code = garage_obj["Count"] as? String
                    {
                        if let garage_cap = garage_obj["Capacity"] as? String

                    {
                        TableData.append(garage_name + "\n"
                            + garage_address + " [" + garage_code + "/" + garage_cap+"]")



                        garagedata.append(garage_name + "\n"
                            + garage_address + " [" + garage_code + "/" + garage_cap+"]")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }}*/
        {

        let location = GarageModel()

        if let garage_obj = garages_list[i] as? NSDictionary
        {
        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let name = garage_obj["GName"] as? String,
                let address = garage_obj["Address"] as? String,
                let latitude = garage_obj["Latitude"] as? String,
                let longitude = garage_obj["Longitude"] as? String,
                let count = garage_obj["Count"] as? String
        {

                location.name = name
                location.address = address
                location.latitude = latitude
                location.longitude = longitude
                location.count = count

        }

            locations.add(location)
            print(locations)

        }
        }}


    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})

}


func do_table_refresh()
{
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

}

GarageModel:

class GarageModel: NSObject {

```
//properties

var name: String?
var address: String?
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?
var count: String?
var capacity: String?


//empty constructor

override init()
{

}

//construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, count: String, capacity: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.count = count
    self.capacity = capacity

}


//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude), Count: \(count), Capacity: \(capacity)"

}
```

}

I have hardcoded some pins for aesthetic/testing purposes but I do not have these dynamically appearing.

Map Controller:

class MapController : UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var receivedData = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(receivedData)
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 39.173294

    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -86.520244

    let latitude2: CLLocationDegrees = 39.163589

    let longitude2: CLLocationDegrees = -86.526266

    let latitude3: CLLocationDegrees = 39.167250

    let longitude3: CLLocationDegrees = -86.515059

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    let location2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude2, longitude: longitude2)

    let location3 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude3, longitude: longitude3)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let garage1 = MKPointAnnotation()

    garage1.title = "Fee Lane Parking Garage"

    garage1.subtitle = "Count XX/150 \n 11th and Fee"

    garage1.coordinate = location

    mapView.addAnnotation(garage1)

    let garage2 = MKPointAnnotation()

    garage2.title = "Henderson Parking Garage"

    garage2.subtitle = "Count XX/150 Fess and Atwater"

    garage2.coordinate = location2

    mapView.addAnnotation(garage2)

    let garage3 = MKPointAnnotation()

    garage3.title = "Jordan Parking Garage"

    garage3.subtitle = "Count XX/150 North Jordan Street"

    garage3.coordinate = location3

    mapView.addAnnotation(garage3)
}
```

}

Comment: Your post is not a question, it's a set of requirements. As such it is not a fit for this site.

Comment: Some free advice: Table views don't store data. They present data to the user, and gather input. You need to read up on the MVC design pattern. A table view is a view object. You need a model object to save your data. In your prepareForSegue method, you want to pass the model to the target view controller, along with the indexPath of the user-selected cell (Or just the row index if your table view only has a single cell. Then the destination view controller can create a map annotation for that object and display it on it's map view.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I was having issues parsing my data and storing it in the traditional MVC manner. Is there any way to store a string of data through that convention?

Comment: "Is there any way to store a string of data through that convention?" What does that mean? "I was having issues parsing my data and storing it in the traditional MVC manner." That seems to translate to "I don't understand the MVC design pattern" Create a data object that holds an array of objects, (or an array of arrays, if your table view has sections.) Pass that data object around. If all you are displaying for each cell is a string, and your table view only contains a single section, create a data object that has a single property: An array of strings.

Comment: I understand I am inexperienced in the MVC design model. I have created a variable in which to store my parsed data: An array of strings in the form of [var garagedata : Array<String> = Array < String >()]. I've also created a swift model to store the data within this variable. How can I connect the garagedata variable to a new model to intake this data?

Comment: @Jared - add some code to show us what you've tried already

Comment: Hi @Joe Niland, I have uploaded some of my code trying to adhere to the MVC model. It is barebones but it is where I currently am at. I am retrieving my data into a variable TableData and I am struggling with linking this variable to my GarageModel. From their I am attempting to retrieve that information in my MapController to display annotations for each location.